# Nightly build generator for Java project

Tags: java, svn, nightly-build

I have a Java application hosted in SourceForge (SVN)
Basically I'm looking for a tool that generate nightly builds based on this:

When a new commit was applied, the tool will auto generate a new build

I did search for few tools but I didn't find what I'm looking for

Comment: You clearly did not. I just appended all your keywords here: https://www.google.com/search?q=java%20svn%20nightly%20build

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess the thing you are searching for is basically called Continous Integration Server. One example is Jenkins. I prefer using TeamCity but Jenkins is much more popular.